# Time complexity of already-descending-sorted array in HeapSort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, analysis, heapsort

Consider an array A[n] which is already sorted in descending order. The heap is already built. Now consider the loop in which we swap A[1] (array indexing starts with 1) with A[heap.size]. Here's the pseudocode:

```
Build-Max-Heap(A) //Already done
while (i > 0) {

     swap(A[1] with A[heap_size]
     heap_size = heap_size - 1
     Max-Heapify(A,1) //Takes lg(A.heap_size) time to float the 1st element down to it's respective position

}
```

We call Max-Heapify on element 1 to restore the heap property by allowing to it float downwards to it's appropriate position. We know that Max-Heapify will take c*lg(n) time. So, shouldn't the loop take c*(lg (n) + lg (n-1) + .... + lg(1) ) = Theta(log(n)) time and not jut Theta (n*lg(n))? Because the heap size is decreasing with every iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum of logarithms of `n..1` is not `log(n)` but `nlogn` (look at Stirling formula)

Classic heap building from arbitrary array is O(n) process - not O(nlogn)

Comment: Agree with 2) and 3) but a sorted array is heap ordered.

Comment: @SaiBot OK, removed.

Comment: Oops. Made a blunder by adding the n...1 terms inside the log instead of multiplying them! Thanks!